# Unable to add single double quote at the end of every line with sed

Tags: sed

I'm doing all this on windows vista 32 bit.
I'm using sed.exe (GnuWin32 4.1.5.4013 version) placed in folder_b.
In folder_a i have file.txt with this inside of it:

```
This 
is
a
test
```

What i want to have is this:

```
This"
is"
a"
test"
```

In folder_a i also have a .bat file with this:

```
call "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\sed.exe" "s/$/\"/" file.txt >> newfilelist.txt
```

When i doucle click the bat file nothing happens. GnuWin32 version of sed needs s/../../ to be written between double quotes like this--->"s/../../"

It only works if i want to add any even number of double quotes to the end of every line.

```
"s/$/\"/"---->Does not work 
"s/$/\"\"/"---->ok
"s/$/\"\"\"/"---->Does not work 
"s/$/\"\"\"\"/"---->ok
```

and so on...

How is it possible to escape a single double quote using sed gnuwin32 version ?

Comment: I just installed GNU sed 4.2.1. from [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) on a Win7 machine and `"s/$/\"/" file.txt` appears to work fine for me, both in the `cmd.exe` terminal and in a simple `.bat` file.

Comment: from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm did you click on binaries zip ? Because inside of it i've found a bin folder containing sed 4.1.5.4013 version. How did you managed to download 4.2.1 ?

Comment: When you say "does not work", what is the actual output?

Comment: @paulo_setar everything I see on that page when I visit it (setup, zip, src.tar.gz) appears to be 4.2.1 - even the 'Version' text at the top of the page says 4.2.1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about batch script (.bat) syntax, which is not a Unix feature.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about `sed` in Windows, but why are you using `"` in your `sed`, and then escape those chars?

Can you not use this:

```
sed 's/$/"/'
```

Example:

```
echo "This 
is
a
test" | sed 's/$/"/'
This"
is"
a"
test"
```

...but that still does not explain this behaviour. With GNU `sed` this works as well:

```
echo "This
is
a
test" | sed "s/$/\"/"
This"
is"
a"
test"
```

Comment: On my sed gnuwin32 version it semms that " is a special character and needs to be escaped through backslash. Your tip surely will work on linux o.s. but if i try it i got no results.

Comment: You need to escape if you use `"` in your `sed` statement on GNU `sed` too.

Comment: On gnu sed 's/.../.../' does not work. "s/.../.../" works well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i've managed to find out a solution.

If i write this in my bat file :

```
call "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\sed.exe" -i "s/$/\"/" file.txt
```

now it works !!

But if i write this:

```
call "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\sed.exe" "s/$/\"/" file.txt >> filenew.txt
```

It does not work !!

So why i can only modify in place rather than create a new file ?